# Issues combining data from two separate databases in Tableau

Tags: database, odbc, reporting, tableau-desktop

I have a report in Tableau I make that combines data from two separate databases. I used to download the data into Excel files, combine the tabs into a single Excel workbook, and union the data within Tableau. I now have ODBC connections set up so I can access the data directly, but I'm having trouble finding the best way to combine the data within Tableau now since I can't union data from two data sources.

I've tried a few different options on combining the data, but I haven't found a way that works very well, so I'm hoping I can get some suggestions on how to best combine the data.

I've tried it with two separate connections and linking the tables together. This works for some measures, but not everything. For something like age, this method seems fine, but when I try something like problem category that has some differences in responses between the database, it seems like the data doesn't always show up in the visualization.

I've tried combining the data sources through Tableau's automatic relationship. I run into similar problems as described above.

I've tried using a full outer join between the two data sources, but I still had issues with data counts not matching.

I'm probably thinking too hard about this, but I can't figure out how to best combine this data since I can't do the simple union any more.

https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b0000BTDkchCQD/problems-combining-data-from-two-separate-databases

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require up-to-the-minute access to the latest records, Tableau Prep would be a good solution. Build a flow that unions two sources together and publish a hyper extract to your Tableau Server as an output.

If you publish your flow to Tableau Server (and you paid for the Data Management add-on) then you can schedule the flow to run on a regular basis to refresh the extract.